# Rename Node and Relationship in neo4j query?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I created node `MonthlyReport` and relationship `GROUP_MONTHLY_REPORT` using the following query.

```
MATCH (group:Group {group_id: $group_id})-[:GROUP_MONTHLY_REPORT]->(mr:MonthlyReport) RETURN mr;
```

But now I want to change Node and Relationship names like **`MonthlySummary`** and **`GROUP_MONTHLY_SUMMARY`**.

What should be the query to update the name of the existing node and relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you will have to install `APOC` plugin:

```
MATCH (group:Group)-[r:GROUP_MONTHLY_REPORT]->(mr:MonthlyReport)
REMOVE mr:MonthlyReport SET mr:MonthlySummary
WITH r, mr, group
CALL apoc.refactor.setType(r, 'GROUP_MONTHLY_SUMMARY') 
YIELD input, output 
RETURN input, output
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time. But I am getting a Syntax Error near `CALL`. @CharchitKapoor

Comment: I am totally new to this concept. It worked. Thank you very much. You saved my day.

Comment: APOC is a very useful library, you should read more about it